# How many stewards can I have in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

If I buy all the Hearthfire properties in Skyrim, can I put a different steward for each?

Comment: Answer is simply yes...

Comment: Well, then grab those free reputation points and write it as an answer, @Nelson! Maybe you can also add a few more details.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103315/is-there-a-reason-to-be-picky-when-choosing-a-steward) for some more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible.
Every house can have their own steward, the only limitation is that a steward can not be used twice.

So pick on of the [34 different options](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Personal_Steward#List_of_Followers_who_can_become_Stewards) and give it a whirl!

For more info: [source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Steward_(Hearthfire)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a different steward for each house. You sort of have to have a different steward in each house if you want to have one constantly in each house.